# nodejs + ssh2 + nodessh

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

i have a question about ssh.

```
    var Connection = require('ssh2');

var c = new Connection();
c.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Connection :: connect');
});
c.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Connection :: ready');
  c.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
    if (err) throw err;
    stream.on('data', function(data, extended) {
      console.log((extended === 'stderr' ? 'STDERR: ' : 'STDOUT: ')
                  + data);
    });
    stream.on('end', function() {
      console.log('Stream :: EOF');
    });
    stream.on('close', function() {
      console.log('Stream :: close');
    });
    stream.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
      console.log('Stream :: exit :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
      c.end();
    });
  });
});
c.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('Connection :: error :: ' + err);
});
c.on('end', function() {
  console.log('Connection :: end');
});
c.on('close', function(had_error) {
  console.log('Connection :: close');
});
c.connect({
  host: 'ip',
  port: 22,
  username: 'root',
  password: 'pass'
});
```

i;ve tried to launch it, but it connects to server and jump to end and close function. i checked that server is on. i've make a connection in shell with ssh2, so i quess that there must be mistake in my copypaste code. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ive found problem.
all of it happens because i have old node js installed, and didnt have ssh2 properly installed